# Ping operation by dynatrace?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, dynatrace

The sitescope tool has the functionality for checking the Ping operation, with frequency of pinging the application configurable and email alerts as well.

Does Dynatrace support ping operation and email alerting ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't to a ping from dynatrace, but that is probably not what you want to do anyway, because it just tells you that the host is up and available via ICMP.

What you can do with dynatrace, is execute a synthetic HTTP all against an endpoint on that host to see if your application is up and running.